# Can I direct user to a specific folder depending on what domain they requested?

Tags: domain, iis-7

Can I direct user to a specific folder depending on what domain they requested?

I have several domains at no-ip.org, lets say NAME1.no-ip.org and NAME2.no-ip.org. In my default web folder i have two sub folders, one of each of the domains. Could I in any way redirect them to the correct folder depending on what domain they are trying to browse?

If it matters i have set up ISS7 with PHP :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no...

Easiest method - if you control the server, set up a different site with a different host header for each site you want... For example:

[image]

If however you can only have a single site, I would recommend using a quick and dirty ASP file as follows (Copy and paste for each domain required):

```
<%

eds = "www.edwardhilsum.com"
eds2 = "edwardhilsum.com"

if request.servervariables("SERVER_NAME") = eds or request.servervariables("SERVER_NAME") = eds2 then

response.redirect("edward/default.htm")

end if

%>
```

For example, renamed the variable `eds` and `eds2` to be unique for each site and change the headers to what you want the site to respond to... then change the `eds` and `eds2` in the actual detection if loop, and finally, change the response.redirect to whatever page/folder you want. In this example, it will redirect to the `default.htm` document in the `edward` folder.

Hope this helps and I have covered two possibilities for you.